# I want a xpath for list of items in a website

Tags: web, screen-scraping

Need a locator for all the list of groceries in a website
(https://www.walmart.ca/flyer) once after opening the site you will get to see many groceries if you hover grocery boxes will be highlighted. I need the list of all those boxes. Please comment if you have problem in going to groceries page

Comment: what language are you using? Please include your current coding attempt, explain what isn't working and update tags via [edit] to include language. You can find guidance on how to write questions that we can best help with, and that will help future readers, here: [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I'm using Python and I'm selenium to get the locators

Comment: Please add your current code via [edit]

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look difficult. You might be able to use a browser extension if you want to open the page yourself. If not, you should be able to do it with screen-scraper, cURL, or Python.